# NPM Won't Run After Upgrade

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I've been using node .4x and npm, and decided to upgrade to .67. Oh boy.

I'm on Mac OSX--new to it.

When I type npm I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

echo $PATH shows a lot of stuff...some redundancies.

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/
```

I've tried a number of different installations, and likely should clean it up, which I don't know how to do :)

Any insights?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If `npm` is no longer installed in `/usr/bin/npm`, then chances are good `bash(1)` has *hashed* the executable name. The hashing saves repeated searches of all directories in your `PATH` every time you execute common programs. Since programs almost never change directories, this is usually a great idea.

To test, run `hash -r`. This will cause `bash(1)` to forget all its mappings. (This is harmless -- it starts up with no mappings and grows them over time.) If I was right, your `npm` will execute the correct executable wherever it lives.

Comment: Don't delete, even if that doesn't help this user another coming from google or whatever could be helped by the alternate solution. I believe only solutions that are technically incorrect and couldn't ever have worked should be deleted.

Comment: @lepidosteus: okay, fair enough. :) Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: Do you get any output when you run hash -r. I do not get any and my problem remains.

Comment: @Ingvi, `hash -r` does not print any output. You can try `type`, `which`, `whereis` to try to find executable programs in your `PATH`. If you're still stuck, I suggest opening a new question with the details, it'll get faster / more attention. Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same problem on Raspberry Pi after manually installing nodejs. `node -v` worked fine but `npm -v` didn't. I was pulling my hair out, checked many times that npm is actually installed and that the permissions are right. Oh, that bash hashing. `hash -r` fixed it immediately.